# I am looking for a way to convert a number into two strings with leading zeros and back

Tags: c#

I have a need to convert one string to another string (4 character always) as follows:

```
1.2 > 0102
99.1 > 9901
1 > 0100
1.44 > 0144
```

and then some other function to convert back from one string (4 character always) to another something like:

```
0102 > 1.2
9901 > 99.1
0100 > 1
0144 > 1.44
```

Can someone help by giving some suggestions as to how I could do this in C#?

**Update:**

Just to make it a bit more clear. There are really two zero padded double digit numbers. The one before the decimal and the one after. So 90.09 would need to convert to "90" + "09" = "9009". I hope this makes sense

Comment: Judging purely by the examples above, 1.4 and 1.04 would both convert to 0104 making a conversion back impossible. What are the rules? To me, a viable conversion back would require 1.2 to have become 0120 and 99.1 to have become 9910 in the first set of examples.

Comment: Are you sure you want `1.2` to become `0102` and `99.1` to become `9901`? Because, if you're trying to represent two digits behind the dot, `0120` and `9910` would make much more sense to me.

Comment: Yeah the first two characters represent the number before the decimal and the next two the number after. So 0.1 would become 0001.

Comment: @MarieJ Then why is 99.1 > 9901 and not 9910

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use LINQ to solve it in one line:

```
string oldString = "3.5";    
string newString = string.Join("", from s in oldString.Split('.') select s.PadLeft(2, '0')).PadRight(4, '0');
```

Reverting is easier:

```
string oldString = "0305";
string newString = oldString.Substring(0,2).TrimStart('0') + "." + oldString.Substring(2,2).TrimStart('0');
```

Comment: Hmm .. now how about converting it back to the original from the result :)

Comment: Added the backwards functionality

Comment: Mr.Jaime, your function may have a bug, please try the number `35` for your first function.

Answer (score 0):

you can start from here:

```
 public void separate(string yourString){
//s= yourString;
string s = "10.2";
string part1;
string part2;
    //
    // Split string on dot.
    // ... This will separate into 2 parts if exist .
    //
    string[] words = s.Split('.');

if(words[0].Length == 2){
    part1 = words[0];
        }else{
            if (words[0].Length == 1){
                part1 = "0" + words[0];
            }else{ part1 = "00";}
        }


if(words[1].Length == 2){
    part2 = words[1];
        }else{
            if (words[1].Length == 1){
            part1 = "0" + words[0];
            }else{ part1 = "00";}
       }
}



public string rebuild(string part1 , string part2)
 {
     string final = part1.Replace("0", "") +"."+ part2.Replace("0", "");

     return final;
 }
```

hope it help

Comment: well your answer (not complete though) makes some sense after the edit, you can decorate it bit more with `PadLeft` and `PadRight` methods

Comment: its not so compact, but more easy to understand. i'm not a master programmer like you guys, but do my best. Hope it help and solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string x = "99.1";
        int real, deci,indpoint;
        indpoint=x.IndexOf('.');
        real = Convert.ToInt32(x.Substring(0, indpoint));
        deci = Convert.ToInt32(x.Substring(indpoint+1));
        string result="";
        if (real < 10)
        {
            result += "0"; 
        }
        result += real;
        if (deci % 10 == 0)
        {
            deci = (int)(deci * 0.1);
        }
        if(deci < 10)
        {

            result += "0"; 
        }
        result += deci;

        float another = Convert.ToInt32(result.Substring(0, 2));
        if (result[2] == '0')
        {
            another += (float)(Convert.ToInt32(result.Substring(2, 2)) * 0.1);
        }
        else
        {
            another += (float)(Convert.ToInt32(result.Substring(2, 2)) * 0.01);
        }
        string result2 = Convert.ToString(another);
```

Comment: Mr.EternaSparta If try to put number `1` it's may cuase an error, like `string x = "1";`